# How to ignore all target folders while reconciling in perforce?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I want to ignore all the `target` folders while reconciling offline work in perforce. I have already tried adding in .p4ignore file the following statements-

- target
- **\target**.*
- target**.*

and few other combinations but none of them seems working.

What exactly should I do in order to ignore target folders and all its contents?

Answer (score 1):

According to the command reference (https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.2/manuals/cmdref/P4IGNORE.html) the syntax you want is:

```
target/
```

Example:

```
C:\test\local\dvcs>cat p4ignore.txt
target/

C:\test\local\dvcs>p4 reconcile -n foo/...
foo/... - no file(s) to reconcile.

C:\test\local\dvcs>p4 reconcile -n -I foo/...
//stream/main/foo/target/bar#1 - opened for add
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I managed this was to add the P4IGNORE environment variable at some common location e.g.
C:\apps\p4ignore.txt

[image: P4IGNORE]

Then add entries to your p4ignore.txt file:

```
*.txt
*.iml
*.project
*.classpath
**target**
```

Note that there are no path separators around the 'target' directory. If you add path separators, the exclusion will not work.

Restart P4V to be on the safe side, although I found that P4V picked up changes to the file automatically.